# gulp version.match -> cannot read the property "match"

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

Ok so I am new at gulp and sass and Im trying to make it work. I installed everything properly but I am getting this stupid error. Is there a solution to this ?

```
PS C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\Desktop\Fax i projekti\Portfolio\Product Landing 
Page Project> gulp sass:watch
C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp- 
cli\node_modules\sver-compat\sver.js:19
var semver = version.match(semverRegEx);
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
  at new Semver (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp- cli\node_modules\sver-compat\sver.js:19:24)
  at Function.match (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\sver-compat\sver.js:374:15)
  at matches (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\semver-greatest-satisfied-range\index.js:9:24)
  at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
  at findRange (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\semver-greatest-satisfied-range\index.js:12:28)
  at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:166:15)
  at Liftoff.execute (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:203:12)
  at module.exports (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:51:3)
  at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:195:5)
  at C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:165:9
  PS C:\Users\Bojan Kolano\Desktop\Fax i projekti\Portfolio\Product Landing 
  Page Project>
```

Comment: Check if you have defined `version`? And error is not _error_ its _succinct_

Comment: Yeah but which version and of what ?

Comment: Ok so basically I had 2 versions installed globally and locally ..... Fixed it now but I got another error :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

delete the package-lock.json and the node_modules folder and install all the modules again! Should work :)

Comment: Similarly, I had forgotten to run a 'npm install' before running gulp. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Unfortunately, that made no difference. Still on a journey to figure this one out. Never had this problem with gulp

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of reasons this can happen. For me, it was because I had installed gulp globally but had *not* added it to my project. Once I installed gulp (`npm install gulp`) the task ran successfully. It should have been obvious but I missed it the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

Removing of  **package-lock.json** and the **node_modules** folder and reinstall did not work me. But it seems like I didn't have Gulp installed globally. So what I did, I simply installed it locally like so: `npm install gulp --save-dev`, and now it works.